# Android SQLiteDataBase: How to read datasets?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am very frustrated here using the Android's `SQLiteDatabase` class.
I have a test database named `db.sqlite` which I have imported to `data/data/[my.app.namespace]/databse` folder using the `SQLiteOpenHelper` class. (Demonstrated [here](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/))
Now I want to be able to query that data base. Should I create another Helper Class for this? I mean if want to use the `execSQL` method I should use `SQLiteDatabase` class but am not able to create a subclass of it!
I'm to Android programming.

P.S: I guess for the `SELECT` statement this is completely different. I want to fetch some data. How should I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to use execSQL or insert/update/delete in your database class you need to add functions like these :

```
    public boolean executeQuery(String tableName,ContentValues values){
    return execQuery(tableName,values);
}

private  boolean execQuery(String tableName,ContentValues values){
    sqliteDb = instance.getWritableDatabase();
    sqliteDb.beginTransaction();
    sqliteDb.insert(tableName, "null", values);
    sqliteDb.setTransactionSuccessful();
    sqliteDb.endTransaction();
    return true;
}

public boolean updateSQL(String tableName,ContentValues values, String where, String[] args){
    return updateData(tableName,values,where,args); 
}

private  boolean updateData(String tableName,ContentValues values, String where, String[] args){
    sqliteDb = instance.getWritableDatabase();
    sqliteDb.update(tableName, values, where, args);
    return true;
}

public boolean deleteSQL(String tableName,String where, String[] args){
    return deleteData(tableName, where, args);
}

private  boolean deleteData(String tableName,String where, String[] args){
    sqliteDb = instance.getWritableDatabase();
    sqliteDb.beginTransaction();
    sqliteDb.delete(tableName, where, args);
    sqliteDb.setTransactionSuccessful();
    sqliteDb.endTransaction();
    return true;
}

public Cursor executeSQLQuery(String query){
    Cursor c = sqliteDb.rawQuery(query,null);
    return c;
}

public void executeSQL(String query){
    sqliteDb.execSQL(query);
}
```

I'm using the same class and I've added these functions and they are working.

Comment: what about the `SELECT` statement?

Comment: You have to write your own quesries for SELECT statement and you can use `executeSQLQuery` to get the data from the query using `Cursor`.